# Is there a system tray-based notepad/sticky note program?

Tags: windows-xp, notification-area, sticky-notes

I'd like to have a program with the following functionality: I could click on a tray icon and have a popup appear with some notes, and then I could click again and it'd go away.

Is there such a program for Windows XP?

Comment: I know that Microsoft OneNote is able to do that

Comment: @MUG4N that's good to know, and i'm interested in payware ones too, but i'd like to know freeware ones as well, pref!

Comment: @MUG4N Is it possible to download a trial of onenote separately from office?

Comment: see here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2010/07/31/download-the-standalone-trial-version-for-onenote-2010.aspx

Answer (score 3):

A few good freeware options are:

[CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/)
[ResophNotes](http://www.resoph.com/ResophNotes/Welcome.html)
[Pnotes](http://pnotes.sourceforge.net/)
[Stickies](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/)

Answer (score 1):

I use [ActionOutline](http://www.actionoutline.com/) for this.  It can sit in the tray and open with a click on the tray icon or with a shortcut (<kbd>Win-A</kbd>).  It's keyboard friendly too, so I can quickly make a note and minimize it with <kbd>Esc</kbd> and never touch the mouse.  It's using 12MB of RAM on my machine right now.

There's a free version that is limited to 7 items per tree item.  The paid version starts out at $49.95, but they occasionally have discounts.  I paid $34.95 IIRC.

[image: A colorful and rather busy instance of ActionOutline]

Answer (score 0):

I use OneNote a lot, but for certain things, like writing documentation for computer tasks, I prefer to use [The Guide](http://theguide.sourceforge.net/).

[image: The Guide]

It does not run with a system tray icon, but you can assign a keyboard shortcut to its Start Menu shortcut, which should give you the sort of functionality you are looking for.  In its options, you can also assign the ESC key to close the program.

Answer (score 0):

I think Evernote has this feature: [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/home.php)